# Cant make VmWare ESXI bootable

Tags: vmware-esxi, boot, dell-poweredge, dell, iso

I am trying to boot Vmware ESXI on my dell PowerEdge 2950. But I can't seem to find an iso that works. when I use etcher I get missing partition table. Please help me

Comment: what version of ESXI are you using? are you trying to create a bootable USB or CD/DVD?

Comment: You shouldn't need 3rd-party software. Either burn the ISO to a disc as-is, or mount the ISO using iDRAC. Is there something preventing these approaches?

Comment: I'm having this same problem, I tried burning it directly with dd, and just opened etcher to find that the partition table is missing.  I think they packaged their ISO without the bootable portion of it which is wrong, but maybe following their older instructions for 6.5 will work.

Comment: The selected answer doesn't solve the problem, but my answer was removed by sysadmin1138 so I'll leave this as a comment.  As stated earlier, the newer documentation for ESXi 7 was dropped.  Also most importantly, ESXi 8 is not available for free as that the pricing model changed, so rather than either shelling out $1k to use ESXi 8, anyone coming from google to this might want to just give up on supporting ESXi 6/7/8 in favor of Proxmox 8 which is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to download the ISO from VMware that has all the custom drivers preloaded for your server. [See here for instructions](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/fi/fi/fibsdt1/vmware-esxi-6.7.x/esxi_6.7_image_custom_pub/download-dell-emc-customized-esxi-image-from-vmware-site?guid=guid-d0af0871-4ea2-476e-a945-d6baa827db25&lang=en-us) (basically go to https://my.vmware.com and download it from there)

Secondly, you'll need to either burn the ISO to a disc, mount it using iDRAC or copy it to a USB drive. Etcher.io isn't the best for creating bootable ISOs, I've had some issues with it in the past. I'd recommend [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/), it has always worked perfectly for me.